# Vim: Replace a word with longer/shorter word without entering insert mode

Tags: vim, neovim

I would like, for example, to be able to replace the word `normal` by the word `short` or `longest` without entering Insert mode.

Would be practical for instance when renaming a variable

```
int normal = 0;
```

I know of the replace mode `<Shift>-R` which works well when you want to replace a word by another one with the same length but is there a way for this use case ?

I would normally just `diw` to delete inner word then start typing in Insert mode but I'm not that familiar with Vim so I'm wondering if there is a better way that doesn't involve Insert mode.

If not possible in Vim by default, I'm also interested in a remap

Comment: Vim questions should be asked on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Questions like this one can be resolved by reading `:help`. No need to re-route them to Vi & Vim SE :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As hinted to in the comment, the easiest way to change "normal" in the code

```c
int normal = 0:
```

to something else would be to place the cursor on "normal" and do `ce` (or `ciw` if the cursor is not on the first character of the word). Note that this uses insert mode to *insert* text. Which is unsurprisingly the whole point of insert mode.

To do so without entering insert mode, one could use the `:substitute` command like this:

```vim
:s/normal/shrt/
```

To avoid spelling out "normal", one can use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> to insert the *Word* under the cursor into the command line.
See `:help :substitute` and `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W` for reference.

This replaces "normal" with "shrt" completely bypassing insert mode. For this simple replacement, this is more complicated than `ciw` above. It's worthwhile when replacing all occurrences of "normal" anywhere in the file by prefixing `:s` with whole-buffer range: `:%s`.

This can be used to rename a variable throughout a file. Although I'd throw in some word boundaries (`\<` and `\>`) to match the whole word only and add the `g` flag to substitute several matches on one line:

```vim
:%s/\<normal\>/shrt/g
```

There's another shortcut: the `*` command will search for the (whole) word under the cursor and `:s` will use the last search pattern if none is given. Place your cursor on "normal" and press `*:%s//shrt/g` to have every "normal" replaced by "shrt".

Comment: I did not know about ctrl-r ctrl-w and right now I am so happy.  Thank you, @Friedrich (and thanks to OP for a question that helped me learn something new).

Comment: @m_mlvx if you want to say "thank you" to OP, upvote their question :-) You may also find `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-A` useful and there's even more text objects you can insert.

Comment: Thank you. I have mixed feelings about upvoting the question, because it does not seem like it shows much research effort, and I'm not sure how clear it is. This feels more like a case of a very good answer to a 'meh' kind of question.

Comment: @m_mlvx thank you, I appreciate it. Your vote is yours, use it as you see fit.

Comment: @m_mlvx as I mentioned I am very new to vim so I understand how this question can seem very bad to an experienced user. I didn't learn with documentation but just by researching which I now understand was a mistake. 
@Friedrich thanks again. I am just now learning about `ce` which seems to be the same thing as `ciw`

Comment: @Youyou well, there's `:help usr` to get you started. Note that `ce` and `ciw` are only the same if your cursor is on the first character of the word. They are distinct and both commands have their uses.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer would be in the comment provided by @Friedrich which is `ciw` to change inner word. I don't think this is possible without entering Insert mode